# Issue with binding SelectedItem to Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**View.xaml**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RentItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding ID.EquipmentID,  Mode=TwoWay}"  x:Name="datagrid1">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding EquipmentID, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**Viewmodel**

```
    public class ViewModelReturnData : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Equipment> rentitems = new ObservableCollection<Equipment>();

    public ObservableCollection<Equipment> RentItems
    {
        get { return rentitems; }
        set { rentitems = value; }
    }

    private Equipment id;
    public Equipment ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value;  ; OnPropertyChanged("ID"); }
    }

    public ViewModelReturnData()
    {
        MyCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteMyMethod, CanExecuteMyMethod);
    }


    private bool CanExecuteMyMethod(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void ExecuteMyMethod(object parameter)
    {
        using (rentalEntities context = new rentalEntities())
        {
            var query = ...
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                RentItems.Add(item);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In ViewModelBase I got the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
I Would like to bind value of `EquipmentID` to my property `ID`, but I don't know why it is not working. Seems like I missed something in binding. Binding the value like this `Text="{Binding ElementName=datagrid1, Path=SelectedItem.EquipmentID}"` works, but I have to bind in to property.

Comment: Whem ItemsSource is bound to a collection of `Equipment`, the SelectedItem is also an Equipment. You should hence bind `SelectedItem="{Binding ID}"`. TwoWay is the default btw.

Comment: In case your intention was to have a property like `public EquipmentID ID` (which seems to make more sense), you would set `SelectedValuePath="EquipmentID"` and `SelectedValue="{Binding ID}"`.

Comment: I just need the value of `EquipmentID` to make an update entity.

Comment: yea, I will try to make it work using your comments.